# How to prevent drag and drop with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I am trying to code a drag-and-drop image uploading thing using jQuery. However, whenever I drag an image onto the web page, it redirects to the URI of that image.

I have tried this, to no avail:

```
$(document).bind('drop', function(){
  return false;
});
```

Any solution?

Comment: Don't know much about it because there isn't much background provided. function(event) {event.preventDefault();}?

Comment: I don't know anything about it other than what is in this post. I have tried event.preventDefault by the way, and it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).bind("dragstart", function(e) {
     if (e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "IMG") {  //detect images otherwise remove.
         return false;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add an attribute to your destination div which prevents the default behaviour

```
<div class="yourdestination" ondragover="return false"></div>
```

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_Operations

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I bound these to functions returning false and calling event.preventDefault(): "drop", "dragenter", "dragover", "dragleave". It seems to have done the trick.